# Get-AzureADUser has an inconsistent changing UPN format in Azure B2C

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, microsoft-identity-platform

I'm using `Get-AzureADUser` against a B2C directory, and upon different authentication sessions, the UPN of the same user returns as either

- `chris@browse.onmicrosoft.com`
- `chris_browse.onmicrosoft.com#EXT#@browseb2c.onmicrosoft.com`

Seems like this is a bug, since the value of a static entry is changing.  What should the UPN of my external account actually be?

This is for an AAD user who has authenticated to a B2C directory.

I can produce screenshots of this occurring.

Comment: Hi, did you see my answer? Any updates?

Comment: @AllenWu I'll have to create the screenshots, but from my experiment, the same command created two different responses and the default directory was set to B2C. I'll have to see if I can repro the issue, or if it's some other issue. Thanks!

Comment: NP, I'll wait for your screenshots.

Comment: Hi, may I know if you have any further concerns about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking what should the UPN of your external account actually be, the answer is `chris_browse.onmicrosoft.com#EXT#@browseb2c.onmicrosoft.com`. It is a guest user which you have invited into your B2C tenant.

The other one `chris@browse.onmicrosoft.com` should be a local account which you have registered into the B2C tenant.

Both will be returned by this command `Get-AzureADUser`. And you can find both on Azure Portal.

If you still have any further concerns, please add your screenshots to make it clearer.